# Why doesn't my terminal output unicode characters properly?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, console, terminal

For example, my terminal does this:

```
$ echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"
���
```

I expect it to do this:

```
$ echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"
☠
```

Why? How do I make my terminal output the proper unicode symbols?

I'm using Gnome 3's Terminal on Arch Linux.

The output of `locale` shows:

```
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? For OS X try: Terminal -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Char. Encoding : UTF-8

Comment: Besides op sys, also specify what terminal emulator program you use (eg, gnome-terminal, xterm, or others listed in [What is the best Linux terminal emulator?](http://superuser.com/questions/80506)), and what character encoding (eg Unicode UTF-8) and font is selected.  On my ubuntu 12.04 linux system with gnome-terminal and UTF-8 and Monospace Bold the skull and crossbones appears ok.

Comment: I'm also using Gnome Terminal... So where do I change those settings? Hmmmm.... I wonder if the face that running `locale` shows `LANG=C` is the problem... hmmmmm.

Comment: @trusktr My locale shows all of items = "en_US.UTF-8" , But I can't stil see unicode characters!

Answer (score 18):

I figured it out. I had to make sure I set `LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"` in `/etc/rc.conf` and `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` in `/etc/locale.conf`, then logged out and logged back in and it worked.  My terminal displays unicode properly now.

Comment: Did not work for me, even though my locale is already correct.

Comment: Everyone is moving to systemd these days. If you're using systemd, using rc.conf won't do anything.

Comment: @trusktr There is no rc.conf ! Just a rc.local    !

Answer (score 14):

I updated my locale with the following command:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en.UTF-8
```

then rebooted:

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 11):

In case you cannot change `/etc/*` files, you can manually set the `gnome-terminal` menu `Terminal`|`Set Character Encoding` to `Unicode(Utf-8)`

Comment: And if I can change /etc/* , what should I do now?!

Comment: That worked for me (with GNOME Terminal 2.31.3) while changing the environment variables did not.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve this after switching to a new PC. I'm using `Windows Terminal` with `Ubuntu` instilled in `WSL2` on `Win 10`.

I tried the suggestions provided here and rebooted; no change.

**Solution**

The fix for me was installing a [patched nerd font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts) and setting the font as the default font for each profile in Windows Terminal settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## with [`localectl`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/localectl.1.html)

Possibly through an erroneous line in my `.bash_profile`, the only thing that helped was:

```
localectl set-locale en_US.UTF-8
```

and then rebooting.

The probably problematic line in `.bash_profile` was:

```
# ⚠️ Better not do this
export LANG="en_US.utf8"
```

Notice the difference between ".utf8" and ".UTF-8".

Before running `localectl set-locale en_US.UTF-8` the output of `localectl status` was:

```
System Locale: LANG=C
    VC Keymap: (unset)
   X11 Layout: (unset)
```

After running it:

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: (unset)
   X11 Layout: (unset)
```

This solved [an issue](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/2050) with running fzf in the Linux virtual console and I can now display umlauts and other non-ASCII characters in the virtual console on Arch Linux.

Related questions:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303712/how-can-i-enable-utf-8-support-in-the-linux-console
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425929/problems-with-umlauts-cant-type-in-terminal-cant-open-files
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16771/foreign-characters-wont-display-in-ssh