# Unicode characters not printed on terminal window

Tags: java, unicode

I can't understand why my terminal window shows output=> ? for the following code

```
class TestChar{
public static void main(String args[]){
char phi='\u03A6';
System.out.println(phi);
}
}
```

Are there any extra requirements for the unicode character to be displayed?

Comment: What OS are you using? What is the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not really related to java, because there's nothing wrong on the Java side. Your terminal window is simply not capable of displaying that unicode character. Most terminals can only handle `ASCII` or maybe `Latin-1`.

I don't know which terminal system you're using but maybe you can change the font of the window to a font that contains that symbol (fonts only contain a subset of all unicode characters). This is not guarantee that it works then, but maybe...

Comment: so what am i supposed to do to make it display unicode characters?

Comment: @bhushanpatil See my additions

Answer (score 0):

What character sets your terminal can display can vary from system to system. Have a look at:

[Why doesn't my terminal output unicode characters properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly)

[Is there a Windows command shell that will display Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters)