# Console isn't showing pretty characters in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, character-encoding, console

I want to write some `pretty`, special characters taken from Web in my Shell Console with `echo` command. I want to write, for example, `▲` character, but it shows me `���` character. How can I solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Linux, Ubuntu 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 64 bit also.  You should check your terminal type and what kind of character-set does it supports. Take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/13898/how-to-find-out-if-a-terminal-supports-utf-8)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly)

Comment: So, to solve problem, I need to change from en to az (Azerbaijani is my native language) or from az to en? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you character sets match and that you are using the correct terminal emulation.  This can be set on both the Linux side or using your terminal client software.

e.g. ANSI, VT100, Linux

Character sets like UTF-8 does include symbols.