# Print full ascii art

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, utf-8, ascii

I am trying to print ascii art like this:

```
print(("""\

                                       ._ o o
                                       \_`-)|_
                                    ,""       \ 
                                  ,"  ## |   ಠ ಠ. 
                                ," ##   ,-\__    `.
                              ,"       /     `--._;)
                            ,"     ## /
                          ,"   ##    /


                    """).encode('utf-8'))
```

And the output does not look right at all.

What is the proper method of printing ascii art?

Comment: Use line feed characters? `\n`

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: Use PyPi's python ASCII art - link <a href="https://pypi.org/project/art/">here</a>.
(Don't have enough reputation to comment unless replying.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`encode` takes a string and encodes it into bytes. That's not what you want here; you want to just print the string directly:

```
print("""\

                                       ._ o o
                                       \_`-)|_
                                    ,""       \ 
                                  ,"  ## |   ಠ ಠ. 
                                ," ##   ,-\__    `.
                              ,"       /     `--._;)
                            ,"     ## /
                          ,"   ##    /


                    """)
```

If this doesn't work, your terminal is most likely not configured to display Unicode. Unfortunately, I am not particularly knowledgeable about terminal configuration; [Why doesn't my terminal output unicode characters properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly) may be relevant, but my ability to help is mostly limited to the Python side of things.

Comment: @frostnational: [I've tried it, and it seems to work just fine.](http://ideone.com/umTQle)

Comment: I get "...codec can't encode character '\u0ca0' in position..."

Comment: @frostnational Not corrupted, it's just your IDE is unable to print these characters. Conclusion, you can't use them for an ascii art!

Answer (score 22):

```
print(r"""\

                                   ._ o o
                                   \_`-)|_
                                ,""       \ 
                              ,"  ## |   ಠ ಠ. 
                            ," ##   ,-\__    `.
                          ,"       /     `--._;)
                        ,"     ## /
                      ,"   ##    /


                """)
```

The r allows you to print raw text better especially when there is a lot of inverted commas in the picture that you are trying to print.

Comment: I recommend this to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
print(r"""\

                               ._ o o
                               \_`-)|_
                            ,""       \ 
                          ,"  ## |   ಠ ಠ. 
                        ," ##   ,-\__    `.
                      ,"       /     `--._;)
                    ,"     ## /
                  ,"   ##    /


            """)
print(r"""\

                               ._ o o
                               \_`-)|_
                            ,""       \ 
                          ,"  ## |   ಠ ಠ. 
                        ," ##   ,-\__    `.
                      ,"       /     `--._;)
                    ,"     ## /
                  ,"   ##    /


            """)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I get "...codec can't encode character '\u0ca0' in position..."

If `print(giraffe)` fails due to an incorrect character encoding then try to set `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable correctly e.g., in bash:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python3 -c 'from text_art import giraffe as s; print(s)'
```

Do not use `print(giraffe.encode('utf-8'))`:

- `print()` function expects a text, not bytes (unrelated: to print bytes, you could use `sys.stdout.buffer.write(some_bytes)`)
- how bytes are interpreted as a text is the property of your terminal, you shouldn't hardcode its settings in your code. `PYTHONIOENCODING` allows you to change the encoding if necessary

Answer (score 2):

#### No need to add `''.encode('utf-8')`

I print ASCCII art all the time using Python 3.6.7 on Ubuntu machines

```
__header__ = '''Content-Type: application/xml

\033[92m        .---------------------------------.
\033[92m        |  .---------------------------.  |
\033[92m        |[]|\033[94m         __   __   *       \033[92m|[]|
\033[92m        |  |\033[94m        /  | /  | /        \033[92m|  |
\033[92m        |  |\033[94m       (___|(___|(         \033[92m|  |
\033[92m        |  |\033[94m       |   )|    |         \033[92m|  |
\033[92m        |  |\033[94m       |  / |    |         \033[92m|  |
\033[92m        |  |\033[94m /              |         |\033[92m|  |
\033[92m        |  |\033[94m(  ___  ___  ___| ___  ___|\033[92m|  |
\033[92m        |  |\033[94m| |   )|   )|   )|___)|   )\033[92m|  |
\033[92m        |  |\033[94m| |__/ |__/||__/ |__  |__/ \033[92m|  |
..And more
```

THEN

```
print(__header__)
```

### And the result

#### [image: Ubuntu-Python3-print(ASCII)]

Answer (score 1):

```
print(r"""\

                               ._ o o
                               \_`-)|_
                            ,""       \ 
                          ,"  ## |   ಠ ಠ. 
                        ," ##   ,-\__    `.
                      ,"       /     `--._;)
                    ,"     ## /
                  ,"   ##    /


            """)
```

this will type or print this in raw text

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.12.0

Either `print(r"""  """)` or `print(r'''  ''')` prints the ASCII art without any error.

space after `r"""` or `r'''` is  crucial and before `r"""` or `r'''` is also crucial to print the ASCII art in desired manner.
In this case once press  enter after `print(r""""` then put the horse ASCII art then after ASCII art press enter once or twice and you are good to go.

```
print(r"""

                                   ._ o o
                                   \_`-)|_
                                ,""       \ 
                              ,"  ## |   ಠ ಠ. 
                            ," ##   ,-\__    `.
                          ,"       /     `--._;)
                        ,"     ## /
                      ,"   ##    /


                """)
```

while `print(r"""\  """)` or `print(r'''\  ''')`, it prints the backslash(`\`) along with ASCII art.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

to solve this issue I just added the header '# coding=utf-8' at the top level of the file and it works.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAnpY.png)

[Result of the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF5rT.png)

Comment: Please include your code in the answer and don't post links to images of code.