# removing the question mark in python output

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, utf-8

I'm trying to remove last character with `[:-1]` from the words that aren't written in latin alphabet (header has `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` set) and removed character gets replaced with ? in terminal output. Any suggestions?

code example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

word = "სკამი"[:-1]
print word
```

output in terminal

```
სკამ?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my terminal output unicode characters properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly)

Comment: Without any code example demonstrating your issue this is not really answerable.

Comment: @max: No, I think the OP has a *bytestring* and removed one byte from a multi-byte character. That would make the bytestring *invalid*, not just unprintable on a terminal due to a encoding conflict.

Comment: See the updated question with the code.

Comment: ah, true, @MartijnPieters. code example makes it look more that way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stop using bytestrings](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).

```
print "სკამი".decode('utf-8')[:-1]
print u"სკამი"[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about u"string".