# C++ ncurses UTF-8 problems

Tags: c++, ncurses

When i'm runnig this program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ncurses.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); 
    const char *mesg = "Просто строка";
    initscr();
    scrollok(stdscr,TRUE);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        printw("%s %d \n", mesg, i);
        refresh();
    }
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I have such output:

```
......
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9989
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9990
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9991
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9992
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9993
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9994
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9995
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9996
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9997
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9998
�~_�~@о�~A�~Bо �~A�~B�~@ока 9999
```

I'm compiling this way: 
`g++ main.cpp -o main -lncurses`

How can I fix it? I have searched in the internet, but there is no solution.

I have tried all variants of `setlocale();`

Comment: how about using wchar_t instead of char?

Comment: What O/S are you using?  Linux?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, Linux, especially Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: And what is your locale set to (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly) among many)?

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs Actually nothing changed in general. I wrote: `wchar_t * mesg = L"Просто строка ";` and he shows: `^_^D 9999`

Comment: Try using `std::wcout` instead of `wprintf`, if it fails you may have problems with your terminal and not the code itself. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs @trojanfoe This is my locale file `LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`  And if i type `$ echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0"`, he shows me skull as he has.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs if i use `std::wcout << mesg << std::endl;` he shows me `?????? ???????`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without this `ncurses` library, but works well:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
    const wchar_t *mesg = L"Просто строка";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        std::wcout << mesg << i << std::endl;;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The important parts: `setLocale()`, `wchar_t` and `std::wcout`.

Code in action: http://goo.gl/MtzMAO

Comment: Thank you, It works, but i still didn't get why `printw();` doesn't work with UTF-8

Comment: Try compiling with `-lncursesw` flag, to enable wide character support

Comment: I think i found problem: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncursesw
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: So probably you have only ncurses and not ncursesw - install the other other one via apt-get. Something like `sudo apt-get install libncursesw-devel`